# Way to hide logic behind class for better readability of method and refactor class to follow SRP

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, single-responsibility

I have an algorithm to create a version for an entity and then I save that version against below 2 entity:

1) Variant

2) Category

```
interface IEntityVersion
{
    string GetVersion();
}

public class EntityVersion : IEntityVersion
{
    public string GetVersion()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IVariant
{
    void Process(Variant model, string connectionString);
}

public abstract class BaseVariant : IVariant
{
    private readonly IEntityVersion _entityVersion = new EntityVersion();

    public void Process(Variant model, string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            Transform();
            string variantVersion = _entityVersion.GetVersion();
            using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                using (var transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        VariantRepo.UpdateVariantVersion(
                          myConnection,
                          transaction, model.VariantId, variantVersion);

                        CategoryRepo.UpdateCategoryVariantMapping(
                                     myConnection,
                                     transaction, model.CategoryId, variantVersion);

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        DeleteStep1Data();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }

    protected abstract void DeleteStep1Data();
    protected abstract void Transform();
}

public class Variant
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class VariantRepo
{
    public static void UpdateVariantVersion(SqlConnection sqlConnection,
        SqlTransaction transaction, int variantId, string version)
    {
        //save logic here
    }
}

public class CategoryRepo
{
    public static void UpdateCategoryVariantMapping(SqlConnection sqlConnection,
        SqlTransaction transaction, int categoryId, string version)
    {
        //save logic here
    }
}
```

I have 2 derived types(`AggregateCalculator` and `AdditionCalculator`) each having their own implementation of `Transform` and `DeleteStep1Data` methods.

```
public class AggregateCalculator : BaseVariant
{
    protected override void DeleteStep1Data() // Is it violating SRP ?
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Transform()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AdditionCalculator : BaseVariant
{
    protected override void DeleteStep1Data()// Is it violating SRP ?
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Transform()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I feel like the `Process` method is doing too much work and if it would be possible to hide version saving related logic behind the `EntityVersion` class so that the `Process` method looks simple.

`Step1` and `Step2` are in sync so that if there is an error in `Step2`, I call the `DeleteStep1Data` method to delete all the data saved in `Step1`.

Also I feel like my 2 derived classes `AggregateCalculator` and `AdditionCalculator` are handling more than 1 responsibility, i.e. running a transformation and also deleting the data stored during the transformation process, although I am not sure if this is true or not.

Is there a possibility to refactor above code to improve readability and handle SRP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, eg the tight coupling to `SqlConnection`, and the fragile base class problem that you risk saddling yourself with by coupling `Process` to the child class methods `DeleteStep1Data` and `Transform`.

The problem with tightly coupling things to `SqlConnection` is that you make the code far harder to test: there has to be a connection to a database, in a know stable state, for you tests to pass and they likely cannot be run in parallel. In short, you can't unit test this code.

So I'd recommend eg passing in an `ITransactionHandler` instance that provides the transaction methods, `BeginTransaction`, `Commit` and `Rollback` that then act of an abstraction layer to the SQL Server classes at runtime and can be mocked in test. Likewise, `IEntityVersion` should be set by an injected value, not a `new` and the two items, `VariantRepo` and `categoryRepo` look suspiciously like they are static classes and so again should be abstracted and injected.

Regarding the fragile base class problem, this is the problem with using inheritance; so don't use inheritance. Have something like the following instead:

```
public interface IVariantProcessor
{
    void Process(Variant model);
}

public sealed class VariantProcessor : IVariantProcessor
{
    private readonly Action _transform;
    private readonly Action _deleteStep1Data;

    public Variant(Action transform, Action deleteStep1Data)
    {
        _transform = transform;
        _deleteStep1Data = deleteStep1Data;
    }

    public void Process(Variant model)
    {
        try
        {
            _transform();
            using (var myConnection ...)
            using (var transaction ...)
            {
                try { ... }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    _deleteStep1Data();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) {}
    }
}

public class AggregateCalculator : IVariantProcessor
{
    public void Process(Variant model) 
        => new VariantProcessor(Transform, DeleteStep1Data).Process();

    private void DeleteStep1Data()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void Transform()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That way, you aren't coupling that `VariantProcessor` to the `XXXCalculator` classes; you are using composition rather than inheritance.

Whether you have a problem with the SRP is hard to tell when your methods as shown just throw `NotImplementedException` and thus violate the Liskov substitution principle instead (I appreciate that this is just example code though). What happens in the real code may or may not violate the SRP. But just having two (presumably related) methods in a class isn't a violation in itself.

Comment: Currently I am using SQL SERVER database to store data hence SqlConnection class and also there is some logic inside transform method but i thought may be its not relevant hence i didnt posted it.I didnt understand your point regarding base class.Could you please share some ideas around designing base class and around derived class for 2 steps please

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow, I have updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Sorry actually I have understood.Is it possible to decouple Versioning part because i feel like that code is tightly coupled with my base class and tomorrow it might be possible that i completely remove this versioning part.So is it possible to design it in a way that it doesnt affect my code ?

Comment: Yes, you replace the line `private readonly IEntityVersion _entityVersion = new EntityVersion();` with `private readonly IEntityVersion _entityVersion;` and you set it via the constructor (ie you inject it).

Comment: Thank you so much.With the help of your code design I tried to refactor my code but got stuck with the problem describe here in case if you have little bit of time to look at it please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128836/how-to-access-parameters-from-action-delegate-and-pass-to-another-method-in-case

Comment: 1 thing I just wanted to understand is that why VariantProcessor  is marked as sealed?Is there any special purpose to do that ?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow, There's no special purpose to it at all. That's just habit on my part. I always mark all my classes as sealed unless I specifically design it to be inherited from (which in truth is practically never for me).

Comment: Ok all right sir.Is it possible to hide UpdateVariantVersion and UpdateCategoryVariantMapping which is updating versions againts Variant and Category behind some class (may be version) so that Process method of VariantProcessor can be simplified ? Is it possible to refactor Process method if you can suggest me something please